# Retrieve data values from a GEOJSON file and input into formula in .py file

Tags: python, pycharm, formula, geojson, equation

I have a GEOJSON file that contains earthquake information such as magnitude and depth for a specific earthquake:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection","name": "event_CATAC2020vvem","crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },"features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "CATAC2020vvem", "date": "2020-11-06 10:22:48", "latitude": "6.887407303", "longitude": "-73.20696259", "magnitude": "4.315760204", "depth": "151.9202271" },"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -73.20696259, 6.887407303 ] } }]}
```

I also have a .py file that contains a formula for working out and printing a result for the distance, d, of intensity values.

```
ml = float(input("Enter Magnitude Value: "))
h = float(input("Enter Depth Value: "))
#Iso = float(input("Enter Intensity MMI Value: "))
import math

Io = 1.5 * (ml - math.log(h) + 1.4)

for Iso in [i/10 for i in range(5,125,5)]:
    a = (Io - Iso) / (1.8)
    d = (10 / 8) * (a)
    d = d - 1
    if d <= 0:
        print("Distance is zero")
    else:
        d = math.sqrt(h * h + d * d)
        print("Radius (km) for " + str(Iso) + " MMI:", d)
```

At the moment, I have to input these magnitude and depth values in manually and would like to retrieve the magnitude and depth values from the GEOJSON file and input them into the equation. Is there a script I can write that retrieves this data and inputs it into the formula? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the bult-in package `json`you can load a JSON object in Python.

```
import math
import json

# Open JSON file 
f = open('data.geojson',) 

# returns JSON object as  a dictionary 
data = json.load(f) 

for feature in data['features']:
    ml = float(feature['properties']['magnitude'])
    h = float(feature['properties']['depth'])

    Io = 1.5 * (ml - math.log(h) + 1.4)

    for Iso in [i/10 for i in range(5,125,5)]:
        a = (Io - Iso) / (1.8)
        d = (10 / 8) * (a)
        d = d - 1
        if d <= 0:
            print("Distance is zero")
        else:
            d = math.sqrt(h * h + d * d)
            print("Radius (km) for " + str(Iso) + " MMI:", d)
```